# How I can use result of first function in other function

Tags: python, function, selenium

I want to place the psw variable ==> in def test_1 / .send_keys()

```
def random_list():
    psw = ''
    for x in range(12):
        psw = psw + random.choice(list('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'))
    return psw


def test_1(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form//a").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='tax_id']").send_keys(random_list)
```

Comment: You need to call the function. So `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='tax_id']").send_keys(random_list())`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Put it in the answer before scavengers like myself do. Haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function. So driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='tax_id']").send‌​_keys(random_list()) – Yevhen Kuzmovych

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way:

```
def random_list():
    psw = ''
    for x in range(12):
        psw = psw + random.choice(list('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'))
    return psw


def test_1(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form//a").click()
    new_random=random_list()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='tax_id']").send_keys(new_random)
```

All Together:

```
def random_list():
    psw = ''
    for x in range(12):
        psw = psw + random.choice(list('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'))
    return psw


def test_1(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form//a").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='tax_id']").send_keys(random_list())
```